# Disable command substitution in heredoc?

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

How can I disable command substitution in the `EOF` heredoc?

```
#!/bin/bash
executableFile="executableFile.sh"
firstFolder="blablabla"
cat <<EOF >$executableFile
    secondFolder="blablabla2"
    if [ \$(cat something) == "blub" ]; then
        echo $firstFolder
        echo $secondFolder
    fi
EOF
```

The value in the if clause should be requested when executing the executableFile

Comment: I'm curious why you're creating a script from a script. Dynamic script generation is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Can you explain your underlying goal? We can probably suggest a better way to do it with static scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting `'EOF'` will disable all special characters and treat the heredoc literally.

```
cat <<'EOF' >$executableFile
    secondFolder="blablabla2"
    if [ $(cat something) == "blub" ]; then
        echo $firstFolder
        echo $secondFolder
    fi
EOF
```

I also recommend [double quoting all variable expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). It's not always necessary, but usually it is and it's just a good habit to get into.

```
cat <<'EOF' >"$executableFile"
    secondFolder="blablabla2"
    if [ "$(cat something)" == "blub" ]; then
        echo "$firstFolder"
        echo "$secondFolder"
    fi
EOF
```