# ssh-add in aws ec2 userdata script fails with permission denied error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh-agent, ec2-userdata

I'm using the following script to bootstrap my AWS EC2 instances after launch. It runs without errors when I execute it manually after ssh-ing into the instance.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_github_deploy_key
git clone git@github.com:myOrg/myProject.git
eval $(ssh-agent -k)
```

After learning about the `userdata` feature in AWS EC2, I decided to use them. A `userdata` script is run automatically by AWS when an EC2 instance first boots.

`userdata` scripts are run as the root user, while I want my project folder to be owned by a non-root user, so I modified my script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

runuser -u ubuntu bash << EOF
set -eu
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/fotobot_deploy_key
git clone git@github.com:fotobot/api.git fotobotFacRegPoller
eval $(ssh-agent -k)
EOF
```

AWS reports that my userdata script fails with the error `Error connecting to agent: Permission denied` when executing the `ssh-add` instruction. I found that the `ssh-agent` process started on the previous instruction is owned by root instead of user ubuntu, and suspect this is the cause.

Why is `ssh-agent` owned by root instead of user ubuntu?

---

Additional info:

- When I replace `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` with `eval $(echo sleep 100)`, I find that the sleep process is owned by user ubuntu, not root.

Comment: The `$(...)` command substitutions are evaluated by the root shell (and therefore `ssh-agent` is executed by root) before the here-document is passed to `runuser`. You need to either quote (or escape) the here-doc delimiter (like `... << 'EOF'`), or escape the `$` characters inside the here-document. See ["How to `cat <<EOF >>` a file containing code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code) and ["Disable command substitution in heredoc?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899041/disable-command-substitution-in-heredoc)